# Moving ASP web application from home server to hosting account

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I need to transfer over an ASP constructed Learning Management System (LMS) from a home server to our GoDaddy (Windows) hosting account. I'm not very well versed with ASP or Microsoft programming but I think it's possible I can do it.

I have a feeling it's not as simple as just dragging in the files on the server and hoping it will connect.

Does anyone have a tutorial example for how to transfer ASP systems from one server to another?

This is the LMS in question http://bit.ly/1w8ZPpb

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ASP.net and asp classic are 2 very different things

Answer (score 0):

If it's classic ASP, rather than ASP.Net, it is mostly just moving the files... at least for the web site itself, if you're going to a Windows server with IIS already running and classic ASP enabled, and there are no *.ocx components or*.dll files to register. That sounds like a lot, but it is fairly common for all of those things to work out in your favor. However, you likely also need to move a database to your host. That may be a bigger job.